# I want to fetch multiple row there is an error in fetch rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to create a page where I have to show records of an specific id but it is showing me this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in line 82.
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in line 82.

this is PHP code of program.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("XXXX","XXXX","XXXX","XXXX");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE cat_id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); //line #82
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $id = $row['cat_id'];
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href='detail.php?id=$id' >" . $row['cat_name'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<table>";

echo    "<tr>";
echo      "<th>name</th>";
echo      "<th>address</th>";
echo      "<th>phone</th>";
echo      "<th>uan</th>";
echo      "<th>location</th>";
echo    "</tr>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: can you show line 82 ?

Comment: </tr>";}  it suppose to be </tr>"; ...

Comment: There's no call to a member function `query` anywhere in your code.

Comment: why exit; in middle of code..?

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); this is the line

Comment: i was checking the code

Comment: The error means that `mysqli_connect` failed and returned `false`.

Comment: seems that you are in wrong file !

Comment: Even check if your using exact column name. Case Sensitive matters with mysqli.

Comment: This looks like the wrong file, the error describes code such as $mysqli->query() being called.

Answer (score -1):

You are not loop through record correctly like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM details WHERE cat_id = $id");
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>phone</th>
<th>uan</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['uan'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

$con=mysqli_connect("XXXX","XXXX","XXXX","XXXX");if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}$id =$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE cat_id=$id";$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); //line #82$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);echo "";echo    "";echo      "name";echo"address";echo"phone";echo"uan";echo"location";echo"";while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{$id = $row['cat_id'];echo "";  echo "" . $row['cat_name'] . "";  echo "";
}
mysqli_close($con);

Comment: Why have you downgraded his code to the obsolete `mysql` extension?